# I'm doing Starting Strength M/W/F but have a PT appointment on Thursday; how to adapt?

Tags: recovery, programs, starting-strength

I've been consistently doing Rippetoe's Starting Strength program every Monday, Wednesday and Friday for two months. Today (Thursday), I've got an appointment with an instructor to go through some technique, which will probably involve a lot of reps with moderate weights in all of the base lifts.

Should I do Friday's workout on Saturday instead?

Answer (score 2):

Just see how you feel on Friday. If you ended up doing some work on Thursday and feel tired, then wait until Saturday. If you're feeling great, then just go for it.

You can also start the workout on Friday and judge by your warmups & first work set. If they go off without a hitch, continue the workout. If you're dragging through them & they are harder then they should be, then just stop and wait a day.

Generally speaking, when in doubt err on the side of an extra day of rest. Just don't use a little tiredness as an excuse to regularly postpone workouts.

Comment: I'm not worried about getting tired, but about over-training.

Comment: @Tim Right, I don't mean tired as in "sleepy" or even "non-energetic" so much as "my muscles don't have quite as much to give" as they usually do on workout day. Over-training is the same thing as under-recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how heavy you go.  If you are keeping the weights light, and just working on form, you should be OK for Friday.  That's particularly true if you *just* started with Starting Strength.  There's a short period of time, where you could recover and be ready every day.

So here's my decision criteria:

- Heavy workout? I need at least a full day of rest.  Move it out one day.
- Light workout? If I still feel like it was a light day when I'm done, I'll do my regularly scheduled time.
- Unsure? give myself a full day of rest and move it out one day.

Either way, make sure you get some good sleep and eat enough for recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably preemptively move my Friday workout to Saturday, but I agree with Greg on the overall approach to moving workouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going over technique with a coach the sooner you try out what you have learnt, the more information will stick in your mind.

So I would stick with the Friday work out. Don't try to get any personal bests with your weights - but still move up so it feels fairly heavy and focus on the technique you've learnt.

Overtraining is something that occurs over a period of time. One day isn't going to wipe you out.